# Is it possible to change state without dispatch in useReducer?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, use-reducer

I found the state.elements was changed in console, even I do not dispatch yet.
What is the reason?

```
const initialState = { elements: [['apple','banana'],['rabbit','cat']] };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
  const changeList=()=>{
    const elementsArray = Array.from(state.elements);
    elementsArray[0][0]='Tiger'
  }

  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.elements}
      <button onClick={changeList}>Change List without dispatch</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, `elementsArray[0][0]='Tiger'` is a state mutation. You should dispatch an action to the `useReducer` hook to update *that* element in state. This seems like a very contrived code example, but what are you really trying to do? Or is your post really as simple as a YES|NO if it's possible to mutate state?

Comment: I made my complicated code simple for posting stackflow. I pressed button several times without dispatch and I saw the elements was changed even I didn't dispatch and also it rendered on screen.

Comment: This is original code in my github.
https://github.com/piaojing/react-zero/commit/f9f6fff18526615923e9adf6b1d95ac5bfc0384d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change state without dispatch in useReducer.

Like any state in React, it can be mutated. The `useReducer` state is no exception.

```
const changeList=()=>{
  const elementsArray = Array.from(state.elements);
  elementsArray[0][0] = 'Tiger'; // <-- state mutation
}
```

Array copy by reference, so *even though* `elementsArray` is a copy of the `state.elements` array, the array elements are still references to the original elements still in `state.elements`. Setting `elementsArray[0][0]` to the value `"Tiger"` has the same effect as `state.elements[0][0]` being set to `"Tiger"`.

Mutations in React a huge no-no, an anti-pattern. You especially don't mutate state or props. State and props are to be treated as immutable objects. This is why state updates always require ***new object references*** to be created.

An immutable update example:

Here you shallow copy each level of depth of state that is being updated. The Spread syntax for shallow copying object properties, and `Array.prototype.map` to shallow copy array elements into a new array.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "update_animal":
      const { index1, index2, value } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        elements: state.elements.map((outerEl, indexOuter) => 
          indexOuter === index1
            ? outerEl.map((innerEl, indexInner) => 
              indexInner === index2 ? value : innerEl
            )
            : outerEl
        )
      };

    ... other cases ...

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

...

```
dispatch({
  type: "update_animal",
  payload: {
    index1: 0,
    index2: 0,
    value: "Tiger",
  }
});
```